# Error using ==> fprintf (In Matlab)

Tags: matlab, file-io

```
R=1; 

N=7; 

fid = fopen('x.txt', 'w');


for i=1:N;

    if i==1

   TO=i-1;

   else

   TO=i;

 end

if (i==1)

        FROM=1;
else

     FROM=i-1;

end

 fprintf(fid, 'R %6.0f%6.0f %6.2f \r\n',FROM,TO,R);

end

fclose(fid);
```

Can anyone help me with the following error? I am using Matlab 7.11.0

```
??? Error using ==> fprintf
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file
identifier.

Error in ==> Untitled at 26
  fprintf(fid, 'R%6.0f%6.0f %6.2f \r\n',FROM,TO,R);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in FOPEN statement. It couldn't open the file `x.out` to write to. Probably due to permissions. Check what is you current working directory (`pwd`) and that you do have write access.

If you want more meaningful error message, test `fid` variable. It equals to -1, if the file cannot be opened.

```
assert(fid ~= -1, 'Cannot open the file')
```

Comment: Another reason you can't open `x.out` for writing may be that it already exists and you have it open in another program. Microsoft Excel, in particular, locks files that it has open so they can't be read or written to by other programs.